# Dictionary that contains multiple values for keys using Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

is it possible to have a dictionary, that contains multiple values for one key?
For example I have multiple IDs (101,102,103,104...) and all of those IDs have some values (colour: green, number: 4, city: New York). I am new to programming and not sure how should I store it.

I was thinking about custom class:

```
class myClass: NSObject {
    var ID: Int
    var colour: String
    var number: Int
    var city: String

    init(ID: Int, colour: String, number: Int, city: String) {
        self.ID = ID
        self.colour = colour
        self.number = number
        self.city = city
    }
}
```

And the create some variable `var myData = myClass()` and just everything there, but then how could I access lets say ID 102 and modify its colour?
So my question how to store data provided in my example with an option to be able select specific ID and modify values belonging to that ID.

Comment: If a dictionary could hold multiple values for the same key, Which value would you get back, when you tried to retrieve with said key? How would the dictionary determine which of the multiple values to return? How would you access the other values? As answered below, you need to store arrays of objects in your dictionary to achieve such effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have two instances of your class

```
let item101 = MyClass(ID: 101, colour: "red", number: 4, city: "NewYork")
let item102 = MyClass(ID: 102, colour: "green", number: 7, city: "Chicago")
```

You can store them in a dictionary using the `ID` as key

```
let dictionary = [101: item101, 102: item102]
```

and retrieve a value by `ID` with

```
if let id101 = dictionary[101] {
  // use id101
} else {
  print("ID 101 not found")
}
```

or you can use an array

```
let array = [item101, item102]
```

and get an item by `ID` with the `filter` function

```
let filtered = array.filter{ $0.ID == 102 }
if !filtered.isEmpty { 
   let id102 = filtered[0] 
} else {
   print("ID 102 not found")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary must contain exactly one value for each key. However, that value could be an array, or a dictionary, or an object etc. etc. so that is no practical restriction.

Since instance of classes are stored as references, the dictionary values could be references to class instances. So you can extract the reference to an instance from the dictionary, and then modify the instance. Be aware that anyone holding a reference to the same instance will see the same changes.

Answer (score 0):

Declare you id with Array and foreach in that ID

```
var ID: [Int]
```